# High-dimensional optimization issue

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, parameter-estimation

This question is mostly related to programing issues, but I want to understand what is going on inside. Suppose I have a likelihood function with "# of parameters $\propto$ # of observations". That is, in order to find best parameters for my model I should maximize this function with respect to all parameters. However, if # of observations is big enough (say, $30$, which is very small from statistical perspective though) all optimization algorithm I have used (I deal mostly with R) do not work in this case (see https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/182179/measurement-errors for example).

The question is how to optimize likelihood function in this case and is it even possible (or one should use another approach which does not require such high-dimensional optimization)?

Comment: Do you mean the number of parameters? Also yes R's optimization function drove me crazy because of how bad they are.. But that is not R's fault either, it's just that optimization is a hard problem.. Eventually I just started taking courses in optimization (convex, discrete, etc.) and afterwards I could write custom solutions to my problems... or at least know which the right tool to use is (e.g. which method/parameters in Optim or how to choose them)... The faster you convince yourself that this is important, the faster you will make progress :)

Comment: Yes, I mean we need to optimize a function $f\in C^2(\mathbb R^n)$ for large $n$. So, do you mean that it is infeasible to find parameters in this way and some other approach **have to** be used?

Comment: Your question is just too general. And no it might be feasible, I am just saying that one cannot make very general statements about this without knowing more details about the problem... And the suggestion was just a hint to you because I also wasted a lot of time playing around with optim, which I could have avoided if I knew about optimization in a non-blackbox way. By the way, you should also note that there might be two different issues at play here: 1) Your optimization problem gets stuck at local minima or 2) you don't have enough data (then you might go for lasso/ridge regularization).

Comment: If you can write down some equations (this will force you to be more precise and less cloudy), then there is a fair chance you'll get an answer here. As it stands, you question is too general.